# Changing a specific string into another specific string while keeping some of the contents of the first string

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am not very familiar with the "Extended" and "Regular Expressions" search&replace options used in Notepad++, so I need help converting strings like this:

```
<a href="http://imgur.com/my7ul.png" class="bbc_url" title="External link" rel="nofollow external">http://imgur.com/my7ul.png</a>
```

into this format:

```
<img class="bbc_img" src="http://imgur.com/my7ul.png" alt="Posted Image" />
```

---

Please note that I only need to be able to convert (link) strings that have images from [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and that I need to be able to convert **every** (link) string that has an [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) image in it, which means that the name of the image files will vary, and will need to stay the same for each string that gets converted. Imgur image filenames contain any alphabetical and/or numerical characters, (including uppercase *and* lowercase characters).

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and it would also be nice if you explain how your solution works so that I can learn something after all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match (assuming your links and class names does not contain double quotes):

```
<a\s*href="(.*?)"\s*class="(.*?)".*?<\/a>
```

And replace it with:

```
<img class="\2" src="\1" alt="Posted Image" />
```

**Edit:** If you only want to convert links of imgur.com.. you can use:

```
<a\s*href="(http:\/\/imgur.com\/.*?)"\s*class="(.*?)".*?<\/a>
```

Explanation:

- `<a\s*` matches `<` followed by `a` and any number of white-spaces/tabs (i.e match anchor tag)
- `href="(http:\/\/imgur.com\/.*?)"` matches `href="` literally, followed by `(` => capture group 1 and `http://imgur.com/` (escaped special characters) and `.*?` any characters non greedy (`?`).. and followed by `"` (i.e capture href attribute)
- `\s*` matches any number of white spaces
- `class="(.*?)"` matches `class="` literally.. followed by `(` capture group 2 and `.*?` any characters and `"` (i.e capture class attribute)
- `.*?<\/a>` matches any characters followed by `</a>` (escaped special character)  (i.e match other things till anchor is closed)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find what:

```
<a.*?href="(http://imgur\.com/[^"]+)".*?</a>
```

Replace with:

```
<img class="bbc_img" src="$1" alt="Posted Image" />
```

**Explanation:**

```
<a                          : litteraly star tag <abstract
.*?                         : any character as less as possible
href="                      : litteraly href="
(                           : start cappture group 1
    http://imgur\.com/[^"]+ : that contains imgur.com
)                           : end of group
"                           : quote
.*?                         : any character as less as possible
</a>                        : litteraly </a>
```

For the replacement part, the src attribut will be valorized by the content of group 1